# How to group by consecutive start time with end time in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to solve below problem to group together for consecutive starting and ending time to calculate the total travel cost for each day in total duration. Here below is an example data and require output.

## Remove all the memory from workspace

```
rm(list =ls())
```

## Required library

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

## Craete data

```
df <- data.frame(CountryID = c('101', '101', '101', '101', '101', '102', '102', '102', '102'),
AreaID = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'),
Period = c('01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023', '02/01/2023'),
Day = c('Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday'),
StartTime = c('7:00:00 AM', '7:30:00 AM', '8:00:00 AM', '8:30:00 AM', '9:00:00 AM', '7:00:00 AM', '7:30:00 AM', '8:00:00 AM', '8:30:00 AM'),
EndTime = c('7:30:00 AM', '8:00:00 AM', '8:30:00 AM', '9:00:00 AM', '9:30:00 AM', '7:30:00 AM', '8:00:00 AM', '8:30:00 AM', '9:00:00 AM')
TravelCost = c('10', '12', '11', '13', '14', '12', '10', '9', '8'))
```

## Output format is required

```
Output <- data.frame(CountryID = C(101, 102),
AreaID = C(1, 2),
Period = c('01/01/2023', '02/01/2023'),
Day = c('Sunday', 'Monday'),
StartTime = c('7:00:00 AM', '7:00:00 AM'),
EndTime = c('9:30:00 AM', '9:0:00 AM')
TotalTravelCost = c('60', '39')
```

## I tried as below but couldn't reach my require output as mentioned in example.

Can anyone help me to figure out the issue I missed in my codes?
Thanks in advance.

```
Output <- df %>%
group_by(CountryID, AreaID, Period, Day, StartTime, EndTime) %>%
summarise(TotalTravelCost = sum(TravelCost))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like below:

```
library(dplyr)

Output <- df %>%
  group_by(CountryID, AreaID, Period, Day) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('Time'), ~ strptime(., '%I:%M:%S %p'))) %>%
  mutate(idx = cumsum(coalesce(+(StartTime - lag(EndTime) > 1L), 0L))) %>%
  group_by(CountryID, AreaID, Period, Day, idx) %>%
  summarise(
    StartTime = format(min(StartTime), '%I:%M:%S %p'),
    EndTime = format(max(EndTime), '%I:%M:%S %p'),
    TravelCost = sum(as.numeric(TravelCost), na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-idx)
```

Output:

```
> Output

# A tibble: 2 × 7
  CountryID AreaID Period     Day    StartTime   EndTime     TravelCost
  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <chr>            <dbl>
1 101       1      01/01/2023 Sunday 07:00:00 am 09:30:00 am         60
2 102       2      02/01/2023 Monday 07:00:00 am 09:00:00 am         39
```

Note that I've edited your `data.frame` correcting the (assumed) typos. If you really have strangely formatted times (e.g. `08:0:00`), please revert to initial version and explain.

Comment: Hi arg0naut91, thank you very much for this support. I believe this a great chunk of codes but when you convert time into "07:00:00" format instead of "07:00:00 AM" then how do you recognize "07:00:00 AM" and "07:00:00 PM" and calculation of sum for Travel Cost could be wrong.  If data have AM and PM hours, then min(StartTime) could not recognize AM and PM. Any further thoughts will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes - an oversight on my side. Please see the edit.